# Get the distance from every element in a list to any other element

Tags: python-3.x, list

I have a list:

```
l  = [10,22,3]
```

I'm trying to create a function that returns the distances (how close they are in the list itself), such that elements on the left of any element has a negative value, and those on its right has a positive value:

```
#optimal output
dis = [[0,1,2],[-1,0,1],[-2,-1,0]]
```

Is there a quick way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [Leonardo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13484577/leonardo)'s answer, to do what the OP commented:

```
nums = [10, 22, 3]
distances = []

for i in range(len(nums)):
    temp = []
    for n in range(len(nums)):
        temp.append(n-i)
    distances.append(temp)
print(distances)
```

Output:

```
[[0, 1, 2], [-1, 0, 1], [-2, -1, 0]]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try a nested for-in loop. The idea here is to just retrieve the indexes of each value and its distance from other values.

```
nums = [10, 22, 3]
distances = []

for i in range(len(nums)):
    for n in range(len(nums)):
        distances.append(i-n)

print(distances)
```

Output:

```
[0, -1, -2, 1, 0, -1, 2, 1, 0]
```

Also, never name a variable `l`, because it looks like a 1.

Comment: Awesome! And makes sense in regards to `l`. This is very close to what I'm looking for. I found that I need to write `n-i` to make the numbers correct, but I'm still trying to figure out how to group them in a list of lists as I showed above